# i keep getting the error "cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

https://gist.github.com/arxheryyy/27b95cb8b7edc49d7208a66dba9ca382
Here's the link to the code on my 'Github' Please help me take a look
I kept getting this error being thrown back at me and I don't know why I've looked through the code multiple times but cant find anything.

Comment: Cannot access the link. Can you please check

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and the link you provided is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are obviously getting the error thrown inside this switch there, between the lines 30 and 36, as you try to use bot.**command** instead of bot.**commands** ! bot.**command** is not set anywhere.

[image]